# Is there a way to subscribe my Twitter and Facebook account to an RSS feed?

Tags: facebook, twitter, rss, feeds

Is there a way to subscribe my Twitter, and Facebook account to RSS, so it posts a message whenever a new post is published in the subscription feed of my blog or another external RSS feed?

Comment: Damn, I need the same thing :( Have been looking for an answer for the last half hour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want [Twitterfeed](http://twitterfeed.com/).

[Create an account](http://twitterfeed.com/users/new), and link your Twitter account to it. Give it an RSS feed, and it will tweet them out for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an RSS feed for Twitter. Just log in to your Twitter account in Firefox and click the RSS subscribe button.

Comment: I asked the opposite question. I want a tweet should be twitted whenever a new post is published to an RSS feed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes use IFTTT or Socinator, both can automate this for you.

Comment: Please elaborate. Ref. [answer]